# Select specific item from json file with d3

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I am creating a project with `d3.js` where the data to generate a scatterplot graph is taken from an external `json` file.

Inside the json file, the data is structured in the following way:

```
[
    {
        "timestamp": 14, 
        "dimension": 2, 
        "value": [
            {
                "value": 5.7, 
                "label": "A"
            }, 
            {
                "value": 4.0, 
                "label": "B"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Then inside `d3` I have the following function to generate the circles to plot on a graph:

```
svg.selectAll("circle")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("circle")
        .attr("cx", function(d){
            return xScale( d./* 1st value with label A */ );
        })
        .attr("cy", function(d){
            return yScale( d./* 2nd value with label B */ );
        })
        .attr("r", function(d){
            return rScale( d./* 2nd value with label B */ );
        });
```

As you can see from the code, what I would like to do is that the position of each circle is connected to the value with label A and B, while its radiance should be linked to the value with label B.

Do you know how to solve this issue? Thanks in advance for your replies!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I managed it, to access a specific I needed to specify the array element number, like so:

```
.attr("cx", function(d){
    return xScale(d.value[0].value;);
})
.attr("cy", function(d){
    return yScale(d.value[1].value;);
})
.attr("r", function(d){
    return rScale(d.value[1].value;);
});
```

In any case, thank you for your attetion!

Comment: The light bulb on my head went on and I managed to solve it :) I replied hoping it can be useful for someone else in the coming future.